# "Applications can no longer access your Online Account"

Tags: 14.04, online-accounts

As soon as I start my computer this message appears:

> **Applications can no longer access your ...@gmail.com Online Account**
>
> Choose Online Accounts from the user menu to reinstate access to this account.

So I open Online Accounts, enter the password and it gets connected.

But when I restart the computer, the same message comes up. I have repeated the process three times but no use.

[image: Screenshot of the notification]

Comment: I have the same problem, and the above answer works for a while, then the error comes back again. Sorry, for not really answering the question, but I cannot post comments, but thought this information is important to add.

Comment: I have this same problem. I just stopped using my Google account.

Comment: @FredrikWallin Yes solution is not working, today it is again sawing that message and now i am ignoring it.

Comment: I hope after this bounty by Freddy this problem will be solved

Comment: Try to run it from terminal like `LC_ALL=C chromium-browser` Sometimes locale acts up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you turn off the "Access your Google Calendar" option under Evolution Data Server the account will stay authorised after you restart your computer. Admittedly this solution isn't ideal especially if you use google calendar but it at least partly fixes the problem and removes the need to reauthorised on every restart.

[image: Google Account Applications]

And press again "Grant access" if comes to the top-bar. Changing only the option is not enough, which it asks at least with 2-step authentication.

Comment: I can't find evolution data server.

Comment: On the Google page of the Online Accounts application the fifth option down directly under Empathy is Evolution Data Server for Google Calendar. I've edited the answer to include a screenshot of the option.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference here. Have things changed?

Comment: @Josiah Quite possibility, This issue may have been fixed and the one you are experiencing now might be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can Try.

remove the account from Ubuntu and login to your Google account in a browser and go to the settings page for your account click security-> then below you should see "account permissions" and remove anything from Ubuntu.

After that try to add the account again.

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The way I solved it was to go to `System Settings --> Online accounts` and then turn-on the button on top right to grant access:

[image]